# Error: host is invalid. parse "https://identity.us-ashburn-1\r.oraclecloud.com": net/url: invalid control character in URL

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am running terraform script which will provision the Oracle DBS in OCI

when I run `terraform plan`

I'm getting below error

[image]

Source code:

`data "oci_identity_availability_domains" "ADs" { compartment_id = var.tenancy_ocid }`

Help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 2):

The `\r` is not supposed to be there in the url.
You probably have a newline in our terraform script. I would remove it and try again.

Windows uses both `\r` (`CR` for Carriage Return) and `\n` (LF for Linefeed) for a new line while Unix/Linux only uses `\n`. So if you can't remove the new line, you can make sure that it is compatible for Unix environment. Most text editors allow to convert/choose the new line character.

Comment: I have not passed any URL to the terraform, it takes care of the getting availability domain names in OCI, checked each and every line, the syntax is correct but getting the error above

Comment: Based on where that `\r` appears in the invalid string, my guess would be that you've configured a region as part of the provider configuration and the region string itself has the "carriage return" control character on the end of it. The OCI provider then presumably concatenates that into the URL string to produce a region-specific base URL for each OCI service.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, the problem is that I had setup the region in Environment Variables, I have used `source env_var.sh` command to set the environment variables, it included `\r` (Carriage Return) at the end of the line.

So just set the Environment variables using `export TF_VAR_region="us-ashburn-1"` command

Thanks to [Martin Atkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281848/martin-atkins) and [JeromeFr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3548287/jeromefr)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run this sample: `

```
variable "tenancy_ocid" {}
variable "user_ocid" {}
variable "fingerprint" {}
variable "private_key_path" {}
variable "region" {}
variable "compartment_ocid" {}

provider "oci" {
 tenancy_ocid     = var.tenancy_ocid
 user_ocid        = var.user_ocid
 fingerprint      = var.fingerprint
 private_key_path = var.private_key_path
 region           = var.region
}

data "oci_identity_availability_domains" "ads" {
 compartment_id = var.tenancy_ocid
}

output "ads" {
 value = data.oci_identity_availability_domains.ads.availability_domains
}

data "oci_identity_availability_domain" "ad" {
 compartment_id = var.tenancy_ocid
 ad_number      = 2
}
```

I ran this on provider version: 4.44.0 and using 12.31 Terraform version.